# JSON serialization - how to unquote a property value?

Tags: javascript, c#, json, json.net, jqplot

Given a class A ...

```
public class A { 
  public string Prop1 { get; set; }
  public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}

string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
     new A() { 
        Prop1 = "ABC", 
        Prop2 = "$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer" }
 );
```

jsonString contains...
"{
  \"Prop1\":\"ABC\",
  \"Prop2\":\"$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer\"
}";

**Question:**

How can I unquote Prop2?

i.e. I want jsonString to contain...
"{
  \"Prop1\":\"ABC\",
  \"Prop2\":$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer
}";

so that Prop2 is evaluated (on the client) as a reference and **not** a string

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You are putting a string in and you are getting a string out. The example of what you want isn't valid JSON.

Comment: I need the value of Prop2 to be an object reference, not a string... does that clarify what I mean?

Comment: So assign an object to Prop2 in the first place

Comment: Can't do that server-side  (Class A is a c# class on the server - an MVC model as it goes...)

Comment: Why not? You've created an object to pass to SerializeObject. Why can't you create one to pass to Prop2 too?

Comment: Because the target object only exists on the client side (it's a reference to an object in a client script library)

Comment: JSON doesn't have any kind of standard data structure for referencing data outside of the JSON. Normally you would provide enough information in a regular JSON object to instantiate the data structure you wanted.

Comment: Quentin, I've updated the question to clarify - hope that helps

Comment: It looks like you're trying to call a specific library function. Normally you would tell the code processing the JSON about that function and not embed it in the JSON itself. If there are multiple things the JSON could be processed with, you would have your code look at the data in the JSON to and determine where to pass the data based on that (e.g. with a `switch`).

Comment: Sadly, it's not my code on the client: it's a charting plugin (jqPlot)... I'm just trying to wrap it on the server-side with an MVC model class.   If I could just decorate Prop2 with some property which says "I know this is a string, but render it to the client without the surrounding quotes please", I'd be all set...

Comment: There is no way to do what you want. JSON purely is a data transfer format, you can't use it to transfer object references to or execute code on the client, period. Besides, `Prop2` does not contain any quotes in that JSON string you show. It contains the string `"$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer"`, but you seem to want to make a reference to a jQuery plugin object. That's impossible, you can stop trying. These things *must* be done via handling code on the client.

Comment: @Tomalak - See accepted answer (I didn't state that it has to be valid JSON, just that the quotes must be removed).  I didn't say anything about "transferring" object references.

Comment: check SignalR if you want to invok a JavaScript method from the server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the quotes from Prop2, you can write a JSON.NET `JsonConverter` for the type and output the property value as 'raw'.

However (and this is important), your output will no longer be valid JSON.

If you're happy with this hybrid solution, some example code is as follows (assuming you've already referenced JSON.NET in your project):

```
namespace JsonRawTest
{
    public class AConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanRead { get { return false; } }
        public override bool CanWrite { get { return true; } }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType,
            object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value,
            JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            A obj = value as A;
            writer.WriteStartObject();
            writer.WritePropertyName("Prop1");
            writer.WriteValue(obj.Prop1);
            writer.WritePropertyName("Prop2");
            writer.WriteRawValue(obj.Prop2);
            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return typeof(A).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
        }
    }

    public class A
    {
        public string Prop1 { get; set; }
        public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var a = new A
            {
                Prop1 = "Some first value",
                Prop2 = "$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer"
            };

            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a, 
                new JsonConverter[] { new AConverter() });

            ...

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can pass it to the client as a string and then use the `eval()` function to parse the string like so:

```
var str = "alert('hello')";

eval(str); //This will execute the alert method.

var str2 = "(function() { return true; })()";

var returned = eval(str2); //Holds value of true
```

Comment: I'm afraid it's a config object which is processed by a charting library:  I can't call eval as I don't want to modify the library  (read the whole comment section below the question for clarification)

Comment: (-1 as this doesn't actually produce the output string specified in the question: please delete so that the question shows as unanswered)

Comment: You can use eval to interface with the object in the usual way?

Comment: In that case you're asking for something that does not exist. If you remove the quotations from around the object you no longer have a valid JSON.

Comment: See accepted answer  (I didn't state that it has to be valid JSON, just that the quotes must be removed).

Comment: I'm sure it works but its bad practice.. The server should never have to accommodate for a specific client. For example, if in future, you decided to create another interface; e.g. iOS, you'd have to write your own custom JSON parser on the client, very wasteful.

Comment: You don't seem to understand the context of this question: this is not specific to the type of client.

Comment: I understand the question perfectly, I am just suggesting that maybe you're approaching this problem in the wrong way.

Comment: Let's just agree to disagree... thanks for your input.